# vim, is it possible to search and replace content inside the register?

Tags: vim

For example, one of my registers "a has content "vim is awesome" 
and I want to replace awesome with "cool" inside the register "a

BTW, I'm not looking using content of register as search/replacement pattern. 
I knew I can paste the content of register a in command mode with CTRL-R a

Answer (score 10):

Maybe something like this. Which is basically take the value in register a and send it through the substitute command and put it back into the register (with the correct register type)

```
:call setreg('a', substitute(getreg('a'), 'pat', 'sub', 'g'), getregtype('a'))
```

Or if you don't care about the regtype when you are done

```
:let @a=substitute(@a, 'pat', 'sub', 'g')
```

would be simplier.

Comment: I'm still wondering whether there is any "vim commands" without using function. (sorry, there is nothing wrong with vim function:)

Comment: @user3663904 this is a vim command. I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean a normal mode command? or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can just paste the contents of a register into a buffer with `"ap`, make your change and then use `"ad` to reset the contents of that register and remove the pasted text